# Cell click cancel in DataGridView checkbox

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a checkbox inside a datagridview that allow user to calculate the total amt of the selected row. 
But I have to make authorization validation that ANY user can tick the rows BUT only MASTER can untick the rows.

So I make the calculation on `CellClick` event.
Here the problem I face is when i click on the combobox, it still will untick no matter how i force it to tick back.

```
            if (e.ColumnIndex == gv.Columns["ColumnMark"].Index)
            {
                if (gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    if (authorized == "TRUE")
                    {
                        gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 0;
                        DisplayItemTotalAmount();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 1;
                        DisplayItemTotalAmount();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 1;
                    DisplayItemTotalAmount();
                }

            }
```

I had already try on `CellBegin` event and `CellValueChanged` event but i will not validated or calculate when i click on the same checkbox second times.

I think there should be have one `Event Handler` for this. Because the `CellClick` work but the mark is still perform untick.

Hope anyone can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Gridview or Datagridview?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...??  - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! - Also: __Always__ tag your question correctly

Comment: Sorry for that, I will remember your advice. I already change it. anywhere thank for read through..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `ACheckBoxCell.Value.ToString()` when not null, will always be `"true"` or `"false"`, never `"1"` or `"0"`. Change this logic and problem solved.

As an extra: fixing this, you'll notice your cell checked state doesn't visually update until you leave the cell. There's a simple fix for that too. See below:

```
private void gv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == gv.Columns["ColumnMark"].Index)
    {
        if ((bool)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value)
        {
            if (authorized == "TRUE")
            {
                gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnMark"].Value = 1;
        }

        gv.RefreshEdit();
        gv.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        DisplayItemTotalAmount();
    }
}

private void gv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    gv.RefreshEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you are working with a datagridview since the tag is for C# only but Asp and c#. So may be you can try updating the `currentcell` value.

```
if (gv.CurrentCell.Value == 1 && authorized == "TRUE")
                {
                    gv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() == 0;
                    DisplayItemTotalAmount();
                }
```

Comment: It cannot work. It like the cellclick cannot cancel the untick or force a untick.